# C# type casting isn't checked when a function takes a dynamic object as input parameter

Tags: c#, casting

I have a function that takes in a `dynamic` type object. The function does work to parse that object then returns back some information about what it parsed. For some weird reason when I take the returned object and store it into another variable, that new variable doesn't check to see that the object type matches at compile time.

I've reduced this problem as much as I can in the below example.

See here I have two functions called `ReturnDouble()` and they both return a value of type `double` the only difference between these functions is that one of them takes an input argument of type `dynamic`.

In the `DoSomething()` function I'm simply calling these two functions and storing their values into an `int` type variable. I'd have expected that BOTH of those calls would give a compilation error since you can't implicitly convert a `double` to an `int`, but weirdly enough the `ReturnDouble(dynamic obj)` function doesn't throw an error.

[image]

In this example I'm using `double`'s and `int`'s to keep it simple, but in my larger code I take that `dynamic obj` object and parse a lot of information out of it and pass back a larger class object.

```
public static double ReturnDouble()
{
    return 1.0;
}
public static double ReturnDouble(dynamic obj)
{
    // do some stuff with object 'obj'
    return 1.0;
}
public static void DoSomething()
{
    dynamic obj = new { };
    int forSomeReasonThisCompilesWithoutError = ReturnDouble(obj);
    int asExpectedThisCompilesWithErrors = ReturnDouble();
}
```

Comment: Don't get it. The methods returns a double and the variable you attach that to is an int. That the parameter you put into the method is a dynamic does not matter to this problem?

Comment: And please don't put code as picture(s). Put it in here as text then people have the chance to copy it and try themselves.

Comment: that's the point... I'm trying to find out why adding the `dynamic obj` make the code compile fine

Comment: Ah ok. I would have found that out easily if i would have been able to copy and try myself ;)

Comment: @Stanton which runtime are you targeting? In .NET Core both lines cause compilation errors even if IntelliSence doesn't show an error. In .NET Framework 4.7 there's no compilation error but execution fails at runtime

Comment: Presumably just a problem with the background compiler to give you live error messages. If you actually build that code you should get problems for both methods. There is no explicit cast from double to int and that is missing for both methods.

Comment: that's what I thought as well so I tried compiling it and the `int forSomeReasonThisCompilesWithoutError = ReturnDouble(obj);` compiles successfully

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using `.NET 7.0` and only one of those lines gives compile error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` is a *dynamic expression* because it is of type `dynamic`.

No compile time (static) binding is done for dynamic expressions. The overload resolution of `ReturnDouble` will therefore be done at runtime. This means that the compiler doesn't know what type `ReturnDouble` will return. You can think of `ReturnDouble` as also returning `dynamic` in this case.

As a result, the `=` operator also isn't statically bound, and so the compiler doesn't check if the expressions on its two sides have the correct types.

Instead, *dynamic binding* is done for them at runtime. That means your code `int forSomeReasonThisCompilesWithoutError = ReturnDouble(obj);` will throw an exception at runtime, rather than emit a compiler error.

From the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1231-general).

> ... However, if an expression is a dynamic expression (i.e., has the type `dynamic`) this indicates that any binding that it participates in should be based on its run-time type rather than the type it has at compile-time. The binding of such an operation is therefore deferred until the time where the operation is to be executed during the running of the program. This is referred to as dynamic binding.

Comment: That's unexpected.

Comment: ouch... what a terrible design... I get it that everything "inside" the function can be considered dynamic, but the fact that they also treat the return type as dynamic is mind blowing.

Comment: @Ralf Its documented.

Comment: @Stanton It's how any dynamic language works... php, javascript, etc. In fact, its better, because at least you can declare the expected type. Don't like it? Design for type safety.

Comment: when I do my Javascript work I do it in Typescript for type safety reasons. I then pass into arguments the `any` type word but pass back out of the function a `strong typed` object. Typescript has no trouble handling this and giving me the compilation errors that I am complaing about in C#

Comment: @Stanton that's only because the creator of C# created Typescript to handle unkown Javascript types, because JS back then had neither types nor interfaces of any kind. There was no such need or expectation when C# was created. `dynamic` was a later addition and *not* very popular, given generics and interfaces.

Comment: @Stanton in fact, what you describe is generally frowned upon in TS because it's inherently unsafe. You're erasing type info only to replace it with an *assumed* type. Nothing prevents runtime failures in this case. It works in TS only because TS gets converted to JS, which doesn't have types to begin with. Types are only checked at "compile" time. .NET, the runtime, does have types which are enforced at *runtime* . For `dynamic` to work, types and calls have to be converted to runtime calls

Comment: The equivalent in C# (also possible and probably a good idea in TS too) is to use a *generic* method with type constraints, not erase type info with `dynamic`. In .NET 7, the introduction of abstract static interface methods allowed the creation of operator interfaces like [IAdditionOperators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3?view=net-7.0)

Comment: these functions I'm refering to are all parsing functions. In the C# example the data is actually coming from a query to a CosmosDB (so it's type isn't known until you parse the data and ensure all the data is there) hence the reason I was using `dynamic`. Turns out using `object` gave me the compile safety functionality I was looking for and I didn't have to change much code. In the TS example it's the same thing, just the data is coming from API calls where there returned data isn't know until it's parsed and checked (hence using `any` for the input parameters there)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is practical to define argument as `dynamic`. Rather I use `object` and when it is useful, then I create new variable inside the method as dynamic.

```cs
public static double ReturnDouble()
{
    return 1.0;
}
public static double ReturnDouble(object obj)
{
    dynamic dynamicObj = obj;
    // do some stuff with object 'dynamicObj'
    return 1.0;
}
public static void DoSomething()
{
    dynamic obj = new { };
    object objAsObject = obj;
    int forSomeReasonThisCompilesWithoutError = ReturnDouble(objAsObject);
    int asExpectedThisCompilesWithErrors = ReturnDouble();
}
```

Comment: I accepted @sweeper's answer because it explained why I wasn't seeing any compilation errors, but this answer actually solved my problem. It turned out that I didn't need to do ANY of my operations using the `dynamic` type and it was fine to just use the `object` type. This fixed my application so it now gives me compile errors as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sweeper's answer explains what's going on. A better solution to the *actual* problem would be to use generics with type constraints, not erase the type information with `dynamic`.

```
public static T ReturnNotOnlyDouble<T>(T obj,T other) 
    where T:IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
    var result=obj+other;
    return result;
}
```

This example is a bit contrived to show how .NET 7 how abstract static methods in interfaces like [IAdditionOperators<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3?view=net-7.0) allow operators and other static methods to be used in generic functions, something that wasn't possible in previous runtimes. I suspect that was the reason `dynamic` was used instead of a generic method.

The [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=net-7.0) contains several operator interfaces now, including interfaces that combine multiple operators, like [IFloatingPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ifloatingpoint-1?view=net-7.0) which combines the interfaces common to all floating point numbers. [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-7.0) for example implements `IFloatingPoint<double>`